# Change view of SharePoint Calendar for multi-day events

Tags: sharepoint, calendar

I have SharePoint calendar control with multi day events:

[Calendar http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_8yYCvwdJans/RuECTJE5OmI/AAAAAAAAACc/iEqKLxyaZ9I/s1600-h/5.PNG](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_8yYCvwdJans/RuECTJE5OmI/AAAAAAAAACc/iEqKLxyaZ9I/s1600-h/5.PNG)

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_8yYCvwdJans/RuECTJE5OmI/AAAAAAAAACc/iEqKLxyaZ9I/s1600-h/5.PNG

Here, the calendar shows "A multi day event". Actually it's an event that starts on the 4th and ends on the 7th.

Requirement: I need to hide the "A multi day event" bar and have it show only on the 4th with the end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for hiding something like that you might want to look at a more lightweight solution like jquery or CSS. unfortunately I can't see the rendered html code at the moment but if ou are familiar jquery or css id imagine it wouldnt be that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible without customizing the sharepoint template (list definition) for the Calendar list.

Comment: Can you explain me how to do it in harepoint template (list definition) for the Calendar list.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the out of the box list definition feature:

(12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\EventLists)

**Do not modify the files in this directory...** if you wish to create your own feature, then simply copy/paste the contents to a new directory in FEATURES (and change the feature GUID), or add the contents to your Visual Studio project (depends on how you want to deploy).

You will need to modify the schema.xml file in the \Events directory. You can refer to this link to help you with that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459356.aspx

Comment: This is can't not be done with sharepoint. Use Jquery and inject sharepoint calender control.